# Kerberos Authentication in Java - does "login" action in java equals to "kinit"?

Tags: java, kerberos

I'm using GSSAPI in Java in order to login to an LDAP server using Kerberos authentication. I'm a newbie to Kerberos, so I'm sorry if this is an obvious question, but I couldn't find anything clear enough on the internet.

I perform the following steps:

1. Define Login configuration by setting the system property `"java.security.auth.login.config"` to the configuration file path.
2. Call `LoginContext.login()` with the name of the configuration and a self defined callback handler
3. In case login succeeded, "pretend to be" the subject (by using `Subject.doAs()`), and connect to the LDAP server by creating a new `InitialLDAPContext` with the appropriate environment variables.

Now, My problem is I don't understand which step correlates to which kerberos action?
Is it correct to say that after the login action I only have a TGT? When do I get the service specific ticket?

Thanks,
Dikla

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The class com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule is Sun's implementation of a login module for the Kerberos version 5 protocol. Upon successful authentication the Ticket Granting Ticket (TGT) is stored in the Subject's private credentials set and the Kerberos principal is stored in the Subject's principal set.

(Taken from [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/single-signon.html))

This means that `LoginContext.login` is indeed equal to `kinit` in that after each of them, we have a TGT.

The service ticket will be obtained and used later - according to the action performed in `Subject.doAs()`.

Answer (score 0):

Never use LoginContext.login because it doesn't support MIT Kerberos cred cache standard for popular OS like Windows, Linux, MacOSX and etc.
JavaAPI is proprietary feature for Oracle environment

kinit and MIT is C libraries and no one alternative replaces it.

If you need specific TGT service to do correctly it's only to use kinit source code to make your own module.

Of course you must also use right way to get TGS without Java modules.
Never use Jaas and krb5Module in Linux/Windows.
Only Sun GSS native is fit for any OS: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/security/accessing-native-gss-api.html

This is important unless you don't want to make your KDC servers failed by thousands of requests flood.